# Servlet and Jsp ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml, tomcat9

I have started learning servlet and JSP. I have created the dynamic web project in my eclipse and mapped my servlets and URL in the `web.xml`, but for some reason, the console shows the classNotFoundException even though I have given the correct filePath to it. Not only this, it ran once in the browser and when the servlet was called, the `printWriter` Object did print anything on the browser. However, I also tried the flush method with it. It didn't work.

What did I do wrong?

### INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
<body>
    
        <h2>Welcome to the number subtraction game:</h2>
        <form action="subtract">
            Enter the first number:<input type="text" name="value1" ><br>
            Enter the second number:<input type="text" name="value2"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>DemoApp3</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Abc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.telusko.SubtractServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Abc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/subtract</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### SubtractServlet.java:

```
package com.telusko;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SubtractServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException
    {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("value1"));
        int j = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("value2"));
        
        int k = i+j;
        
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println(k);
          //also tried the flush method. it didnt work.. 

    }
}
```

### console:error:

```
May 04, 2022 3:20:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.53]
May 04, 2022 3:21:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9494"]
May 04, 2022 3:21:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [611] milliseconds
May 04, 2022 3:21:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet [Abc] as unavailable
May 04, 2022 3:21:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [Abc]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.telusko.SubtractServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:538)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1049)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:767)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. For me, your code works well.

I guessed two the reasons of error.

One reason is .class file.is not created. In this case,

I don't know what IDE you use. In intellij IDE, you can check target directory. You must have .class file under here.
[target directory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcQf5.png)

The other reason I guess is your project structrue have something wrong.

you can check is video to create sample servlet project in Intellij. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3-d65fjzMQ